# What's a simple "colour picker" app for GNOME?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, colors

I need a small tool to ‘pick’ a colour anywhere on the screen (so that I basically get the [hex code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) for it). Earlier, I've used KDE's [KColorChooser](http://kde.org/applications/graphics/kcolorchooser/) for this.

According to [this page](http://wakish.info/color-picker-alternative-for-ubuntu-gnome-colorpicker-for-linux/), "Gpick" sounds like what I want, but:

```
$ apt-cache search gpick
<returns nothing>
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## gpick

That's strange that you couldn't install `gpick`, as I get the following :

```
apt-cache search gpick
gpick - advanced GTK+ color picker
```

I suppose it could be in a source that you currently don't have enabled..

To pick a colour, launch Gpick, lcick on the swatch, and then press space when your mouse hovers over the colour you want to record.

[image]

## gcolor2

(not anymore available in Ubuntu 19.04+)

That being said for simple colour picking I prefer `gcolor2` - Nice and simple to use and should do exactly what you require.

You can install it with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcolor2
```

## gcolor3

gcolor2 is not on the Ubuntu repositories anymore, and has been replaced with gcolor3.

[image: gcolor3]

You can install it with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcolor3
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, looking around at http://packages.ubuntu.com/, it seems gpick just isn't available for 11.04 (Natty). However, gcolor2 does exactly what I want, so I won't investigate the gpick issue further :)

Comment: It is a shame gcolor2 is not in the repositories in Ubuntu 19.04!

Comment: `gpick` is in the repositories for Ubuntu 20.04 , but not `gcolor2`

Comment: Both programs do not work on Wayland

Answer (score 14):

I like to use the software agave. It's a simple software that gives your color combinations, and it has a color picker.

```
sudo apt-get install agave
```

Worth give it a try!

Regards

Comment: +1. Agave does this too, and it seems to use the exact same component that is basically the [gcolor2 tool](http://askubuntu.com/q/82049/928). (I'm accepting gcolor2 because it's a nice minimal solution, giving this functionality and nothing else.)

Comment: Agave is no longer available. It has been discontinued and removed from the official repositories.

Answer (score 9):

`grabc` is as simple as it can get. Spawns a cursor, outputs color on stdout when you click. Pure Unix way.

```
$ grabc
#f47276
244,114,118
```

To install it, run `sudo apt install grabc`.

Comment: awesome. just setting up a keyboard shortcut for `grabc | xclip -i`

Comment: This one is available in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories.

Answer (score 3):

There's a native color picker for HTML5's [`<input>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/color) built into all modern browsers (some [screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339827/15347451)).

Enter this in browser's URL bar:

```
data:text/html,<input type="color" />
```

and click on the rendered button. Bookmark for later use. Works offline.

(Technically, this is neither a dedicated app, nor GNOME-specific; which might exactly be the point: no install needed)

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't mention, `gcolor2` can also sample color from all over the desktop.

But I got curious about `gpick`, and tried to install a newer version on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty. So I got:

- [liblua5.2-0_5.2.0-2_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/liblua5.2-0/download) for `precise` (there's no earlier); installs in `natty` via GDebi Package Installer
- [gpick_0.2.5-1_i386.deb](http://code.google.com/p/gpick/downloads/detail?name=gpick_0.2.5-1_i386.deb) from their code.google.com website; installs in `natty` via GDebi Package Installer (with previous dependency installed)

... however, at this point:

```
$ gpick 
gpick: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by gpick)
```

Then I tried getting [libstdc++6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libstdc++6/download) and extracting (not installing) it; and using this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/Desktop/libstdc++6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu gpick
gpick: symbol lookup error: gpick: undefined symbol: g_dbus_object_manager_server_new
```

... damn, so it needs more dependencies satisfaction (and if one starts messing with libc, one may as well update the OS `:)` )

Anyways, back to `gpicks` [webpage](http://code.google.com/p/gpick/), there is a link [PPA at Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethezbyg/+archive/ppa) there - so I got `gpick_0.2.0-1~ppakarmic1_i386.deb` from the PPA [Packages ...](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethezbyg/+archive/ppa/+packages) page. Installed it again via GDebi Package installer (removing the previous, newer one first, with `sudo dpkg -r gpick`) - and it works! And even if it's not the latest version, I think it looks quite awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the X11 *native* solution that

- doesn't require any external packages like Agave, Gpick, or Grabc etc (like all existing solutions).
- and it doesn't limit to web pages (like the browser based answer) either

Just run `xmag`. From its man page:

- The  `xmag` program allows you to magnify portions of an X screen.
- The area can be dragged out to the desired size by pressing Button  2.
- Once  a region has been selected, a window is popped up showing a blown up version of the region in which each pixel in the source  image  is  represented  by  a  small square of the same color.
- *"Pressing Button1 in the enlargement window shows the position and RGB value of the pixel  under the  pointer  until  the button is released"* -- this, is the X11 native solution for Color Picker.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get a simple color picker is to install yad (Yet Another Dialog) and run `yad --color`.

Comment: Simple, for those who need `yad` for their shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend GPick:

sudo apt-get install gpick

Applications -> Graphics -> GPick

It's got a lot more features than gcolor2 but is still extremely simple to use - click on one of the hex swatches, move your mouse around the screen over the colours you want to pick, then press the space bar to add to your swatch list.

It also has a traditional colour picker (like gcolor2) in the bottom right-hand corner of the window to allow you to pick individual colours with magnification.

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome Shell extension [Color Picker](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3396/color-picker/) provides a picker and a color palette, generated from previously selected colors.

### The picker

[image]

### The color palette

[image]

Source: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3396/color-picker/

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle getting eiter `gpick` or `gcolor3` running: it seems neither of those work on Wayland. However, there is an even simpler tool called [wl-color-picker](https://github.com/jgmdev/wl-color-picker) that does the job.

[image: wl-color-picker]